# Should Read Permissions users be able to see Site Actions on site home?

Tags: 2010, permissions, site, read-only

Within a test site, I have a test user set to read permissions.  When the test user visits the homepage to that site, the yellow up folder icon is present but the Site Actions is not visible.  Should it be; and is this the default behavior for SharePoint 2010?  If so, may I modify it such that it shows Site Actions and then View All Site Content?
Sorry for the multi-part.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please confirm if ant Custom master page is used?

Comment: I have made a few attempt to change but it is reverted to default now.  I have the same result.

Comment: More info: If I create a Team site and turn on Publishing, the Site Actions, along with other ribbon icons go away for read only permissions.  This seems to make sense, but it's not clear in documentation I've read.  If I turn off publishing, the Site Action returns.